# bootstrap navbar -right messed up

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to display a navbar on top of my webpage. Right side has two elements: if user not logged in, they should be Login and Register; if user already logged in, they should be "Hi, >username<" and Logout. My code below only works when user not logged in. After they logged in, right part became:
Hi, Logout

> username<

Please help me out.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
    </button>
  </div>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li><a href="member.php?lang=en">English</a></li>
      <li><a href="member.php?lang=zh">中文</a></li>
      <li><a href="<?php echo lnkIndex; ?>"><img alt="KnowSG.com" src="images/knowsg_icon.png" style="height:20px"/></a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <?php
        if(isset($_SESSION["valid_user"])) {
          $msg = "<li>Hi, <a href=\"".lnkMember."\">".$_SESSION["valid_user"]."</a></li><li><a href=\"".lnkLogout."\">".strLogout."</a></li>";
          echo $msg;
        }
        else {
          echo "<li><a href=\"".lnkLogin."\">".strLogin."</a></li><li><a href=\"".lnkRegister."\">".strRegistr."</a></li>";
        }
      ?>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
</nav>
```

Comment: check `session_start()` is placed in top of the page

Comment: @TamilSelvan yes session start already used. The problem is not username not shown, but username is displayed on the wrong place.

Comment: let paste a view source code when logged in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a `<p class="navbar-text">` inside your `<li>`, like this:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li>
        <p class="navbar-text">
            Hi, <a href="/foo.php" class="navbar-link">USER</a>
        <p>
    </li>
    <li><a href="/bar.php">Log out</a></li>
</ul>
```

(`navbar-link` is not mandatory, it makes the username grey instead of blue)